# Windows 10 docker desktop keeps showing Kubernetes is starting

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows

I checked the `Enable Kubernetes` in windows Docker Desktop and it keeps circling and showing `Kubernetes is starting...`

I searched and couldn't find any proper answer. Some advises are about deleting Docker Desktop and reinstalling it.

I want to know any other solution Before pushing kill switch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked for me.

First of all open a new PowerShell.
We need to have Kubernetes server installed and running. So execute this command:

> **kubectl version**

I faced this line in the bottom of response:

> **Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex:**
> **No connection could be made because the target machine actively**
> **refused it.**

If you got some similar response, it means Windows cannot resolve the internal domain which should be set in the `hosts` file. So do as the following instructions:

1. Open the hidden path

> **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

`hosts` file has no extension. Open it with notepad or any text editor. Do it with **Adminisrator** privilege.

2. insert this line in the opened hosts file:

> **127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal**

3. Save it.
4. Run Docker Desktop again.

And that's it.

**For checking the Kubernetes installation success, follow below instructions:**

Docker Desktop will not show Kubernetes as **installed** until all of the Kubernetes components are running. To see what is happening with its components open a new PowerShell to have the necessary environment variables set and run:

Open PowerShell and run this command:

> **kubectl get all -n kube-system**

Check if the followings are true:

```
1) all of the pods have “Running” status.
2) deamonset.apps/kube-proxy has “1” in the “Ready” column
3) deployment.apps/coredns has “2/2” in the “Ready” column
4) replicaset.apps/coredns-HASH has “2” in the “Ready” column
```

If any of the above statements are not true, use `kubectl describe -n kube-system OBJECTNAME` for more details.
For example:

> **kubectl describe -n kube-system pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-99qxd**

You could be found more in this complete [**discussion**](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-install-kubernetes-stuck-on-starting-state/117048).

I am still eager for new answer and discussions.